truck won’t start and no lights at all
I’ve been having issues with my 2014 Silverado 1500. Went to start it earlier and nothing came on. No dashlights,no dings,the side steps didn’t come out when I opened the door. Waited a bit and all the lights came on. Went to have the battery tested And it passed. Also when it does finally start,the charge holds. But it’s occurring more and more.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What your describing seems to me to be a problem with the connection to the battery itself. Something like one of the four main places the battery leads connect to is sometimes not allowing a complete circuit. You might want to check them for corrosion or other issues.
